# Populating singleton Map

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
public class SomeClass{

  private static volatile TreeMap<String, SomeData> map;

  public static TreeMap<String,String> getSingletonMap(){

      if(map=null){
        synchronized(SomeClass.class){
          if(map==null){
             map = new TreeMap<>();
           }
        }
       }
     return map;
   }

 public static synchronized void add(SomeData data){
     TreeMap<String,String> treeMap = getSingletonMap();
     treeMap.put(data.key, data);
 }

 public final class SomeData{
     String key;
     public SomeData(String key){
        this.key = key;
     }

 }
```

}

```
public class SomeOtherClass{

    //this method is called by multiple threads
    public static synchronized collectData(){
        try{
             //do some iteration here and add data at every iteration
             for(String str : strings){
                 SomeClass.add(new SomeClass.SomeData(string));
              }
         }
         finally{
           //do some processing of collected data by main Thread
           // at this point TreeMap of SomeClass is null;
         }
     }

}
```

}

Every time different thread is accessing the loop and adding data, the TreeMap is initialised again. And in the finally block, when the main thread continues, it also gets initialised again, but the TreeMap is supposed to be a singleton. What am I missing here? Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us real code, or better: a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. This code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Your code won't compile, so please show us the code you're really using. Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Maybe there is something wrong with your test structure: make sure that `strings` in `collectData()` isn't always the same, because a new `key` will override an old key if they are *equal*. And make sure that you check the content of `map` after you "slept" or "waited" some time, because the main thread won't wait until the child threads populated that map.

Comment: Thanks for the interest. The code looks literally the same apart from method/class names. What is happening in the collectData is that many different threads feed the TreeMap with different data. It's not possible for me to paste the code for that class as it has lot of dependencies and there  is lot of other code around but the only part when it is populated by threads is here.

Comment: Which java version are you using ? You're not using Java 1.4 are you ?

Comment: `map=null` this won;t compile, as other suggested as well. In fact there are many compilation errors.

Comment: Why do you want to use double locking for singleton? It already has got fair share of problems.

Comment: @akhil_mittal Before using another pattern, I think it's good to understand **exactly** what's wrong with the current one. Here's a great chance to learn something.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different Singleton implementations. What you are doing is known as ["**double checked locking**"](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html?page=2). Before Java 5 this was known as a "broken" pattern. Even a `volatile` keyword couldn't fix it. But as of Java 5 they [fixed the `volatile` keyword](http://crackingjavainterviews.blogspot.be/2013/05/what-is-double-checked-locking-problem.html). **So your pattern is correct.**

However if you use **multiple VMs** (for example sharing objects with JNDI) then this could be insufficient. The serialization can break it. Another way to break it, is the use of multiple classloaders.

These days singletons are often implemented using `enum`'s. You can make them support multiple VMs by implementing the following private method.

```
  private Object readResolve() {
        return INSTANCE;
  }
```

There are other ways and side cases, which are also explained [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html?page=2).

Comment: Thanks. That shouldn't ever happen in this case that 2 threads enter the getSingletonMethod() as this method is called from another synchronized method. I dig more into the code (btw. this is a clustered environment - perhaps I should mentioned that ealier) and I suspect that this is an effect of multiple JVMs sharing data, which would make sense as the singleton can be a singleton per single JVM and other kind of coordination is required in case of multi JVMs. I guess that is the case.

Comment: Jup that's the reason ! The serialization doesn't check it properly. Maybe you should just make it `transient` ? Alternatively some solutions are proposed here: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html?page=2

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in getSingletonMap function

```
if( map = null )
```

should be

```
if( map == null )
```

But all of this lazy initialization is pointless since your add method is synchronized. You are not gaining any performance benefit, and you have made your code much more complex. Creating an empty map is not expensive: get rid of the getSingletonMap method completely:

```
private static final TreeMap<String, SomeData> map = new TreeMap<>();

public static synchronized void add( SomeData data ) {
    map.put( data.key, data );
}
```

Comment: Correct looks like that is what he trying to do. or better just create ConcurrentHashMap and remove synchronized from add method. That would be better than static synchronized.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I typed the code by hand... the if(map-null) wouldnt even compile. The code compile and run fine. Initialising map at the declaration line would simply empty per thread. But as I said above this might be related to processing in clustered environment. The singleton implementation itself if perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

tree map it self need to be synchronized use this way to do so

```
SortedMap m = Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(new TreeMap(...));
```

or also you can use `Map<String, String> treeMap = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, String>();`

Comment: I used ConcurrentHashMap for tests but the result remains the same. I rather wonder why TreeMap gets re-initialised per thread.

Comment: most likely it is issue in the treemap itself because I note that if many thread try access the same object in the treemap it is not thread safe, thats why the came with new ConcurrentSkipListMap

Comment: see, if you change your code to Hashtable, just for testing is it behave the same